# systemctl list-unit-files fails - "Not a directory"

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I am new to Ubuntu and systemd (was a long time away from Linux) and I was trying out `systemctl list-unit-files` - oddly it failed with the message "Not a directory". The command `systemctl list-units` seems to work fine though. I googled around, and looked here, but I couldn't find a mention of this error condition. My installation (16.04.1 LTE) is only a day old, so I hardly think it could be corruption yet.

What is this error, and how should I have gone about finding what was wrong?

Comment: Just to let you know I have a relatively fresh install of `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` and `systemctl list-unit-files` works perfectly. Perhaps you can edit your question and copy & paste in the exact screen contents of calling the conmand and the resulting output. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually found the problem by probing the log. Silly mistake, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, poked around in `journalctl` and got some hints and realized what had gone wrong. I had installed a new Cuda service configuration file with the command:

```
  cp nvidia-persistenced.service /usr/lib/systemd/system
```

in the naive assumption that `system` was a directory that the service configuration file would be copied into. However in reality that `system` subdirectory did not exist yet, so the `cp` command just created a file in that place with the name "system". I assume that this in turn confused the `systemctl list-unit-files` command which was expecting a subdirectory there.

Kind of a silly error, but posting it in case it helps someone else as googling that message turned up nothing
. BTW, `systemctl list-unit-files` works fine now and so do my cuda examples.

Comment: There are many **quirks** with nVidia and Linux. Thanks for sharing.